# Google maps v3 geocoder: callback for latitude and longitude

Tags: callback, geocode

I can create a Google map that centers on Niwot, CO using geocode. If I click the "Encode" button from the form (which I got from Google's website), it puts a marker on the map in the correct location.

My question is: How do I retrieve the position coordinates (latitude and longitude) using the javascript callback function? I need to put the lat and long into my database.

Also, right now I'm using this for just one place for troubleshooting, but I'll then need it for numerous addresses.

Code is below.

var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.171776, -105.116737);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

}

function codeAddress() {

var address = 'Niwot, CO';//this will eventually be an array
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results) {

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location

    });
```

//code below added based on comment 1; how do I display that lat and lng? I'll need to do this for troubleshooting.

```
    var latlng = results[0].geometry.location; 
    var lat = latlng.lat(); 
    var lng = latlng.lng();
```

});
  }

Answer (score 2):

The location returned is an instance of the LatLng class. You can call lat() to get the latitude and lng() to get the longitude. e.g.

var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
var lat = latlng.lat();
var lng = latlng.lng();

Here are the relevant docs:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

Comment: Thanks. I've read the documentation but I don't know javascript, so I don't know how to modify my code. I know that the latitude and longitude are stored in the "position", and you've shown how to define those variables. How would I display them on the page? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside your geocode call

```
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': 'CA, US'}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     location = results[0].geometry.location;
   alert(location)
    } 
  });
```

This will show the latitude and longitude of the address.

> (lat,lng)